# Issue installing openwhisk with incubator-openwhisk-devtools

Tags: openwhisk

I have a blocking issue installing openwhisk with docker

I typed make quick-start right after a git pull of the project incubator-openwhisk-devtools. My OS is Fedora 29, docker version is 18.09.0, docker-compose version is 1.22.0. JDk 8 Oracle.

I get the following error:

```
[...]
adding the function to whisk ...
ok: created action hello
invoking the function ...
error: Unable to invoke action 'hello': The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). (code ciOZDS8VySDyVuETF14n8QqB9wifUboT)
[...]
[ERROR] [#tid_sid_unknown] [Invoker] failed to ping the controller: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for health-0: 30069 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
[ERROR] [#tid_sid_unknown] [KafkaProducerConnector] sending message on topic 'health' failed: Expiring 1 record(s) for health-0: 30009 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Please note that `controller-local-logs.log` is never created. 
If I issue a `touch controller-local-logs.log` in the right directory the log file is always empty after I try to issue make quick-start again.
`http://localhost:8888/ping` gives me the right answer: pong.
`http://localhost:9222` is not reacheable.

Where am I wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Then, if I issue make restart-controller, the procedure hangs adding a dot after the other.